# memcpy segment fault, what's wrong with this code?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, memcpy

my software is a Web Crawler,when I get  the body from the http response, it cracks.

```
resp->body = Malloc(content_len);
memcpy(resp->body, body_start, content_len); //THIS IS THE FAULTY LINE
```

Malloc is a wrapper function of malloc,so resp->body is not NULL, and content_len is the length of memory area begin with body_start,but its content is  "PK\003\004\024", "\003" is ETX(end of text), "\004" is EOT(end of transmission),"\024" is device control 4,I really don't know what 's the meaning of these strange chracters,why does it crack?

Comment: How do you initialize `body_start`?  Obviously that is the most likely culprit.

Comment: body_start is the pointer of the body start of http response.I have checked error,so when the program run memcpy ,body_start is initilized correctly

Comment: Forgive me if I don't take your word for it.

Comment: understood.many people think their code is right, but actually the code is false. but for me I have added many assert macros,and used gdb to trace the code.Anyway,thanks for your help.@ED S.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The body is ZIP encoded, from the [ZIP wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format));

> Magic number
>     none, though **PK\003\004**, PK\005\006 (empty archive), or PK\007\008 (spanned archive) are common.

You'll need to check the header and unzip the body before reading it.

As for the segmentation fault, any of the 3 parameters to memcpy could be the culprit, code showing their initialisation is required to spot the exact problem. If you're using any of the string functions (strlen/strcpy) on the body in a non shown part of the code, they're likely to break with binary input like this.

Comment: thanks for your reply.the url seems link to  a zip file. and the program downloads it,but when I send a http request, I have added "Accept: text/html" to the request header,and the server still gives me a zip file.

Comment: @YuYang If you're requesting a zip and there is no alternative encoding the server can do, most web servers will send the file anyway.

Comment: Yes, I get the error,the function to filter urls don't contain zip.thank you very much.....